# Managing multiple databases with NHibernate and Autofac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, autofac, multiple-databases

I thought I'd get this question out there while I noodled on a solution on my own.

After having built out the bulk of an application, I have a last minute requirement to support reading/writing to an additional database (2 total, no known others).  I built the application using NHibernate, with Autofac supplying the DI/IoC components.  FWIW, this resides in an ASP.NET MVC 2 app.

I have a generic repository class that takes an NHibernate session.  Theoretically, I can continue to use this generic repository (`IRepository<>`) for the second database so long as the session that gets passed to it is spawned from an appropriate SessionFactory, right?

Well, when the app starts, Autofac does it's thing.  With regards to the Session and SessionFactory, I have a module that states:

```
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
    .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(WebLifetime.Request)
    .OnActivated(e =>
    {
        e.Context.Resolve<TransactionManager>().CurrentTransaction = ((ISession)e.Instance).BeginTransaction();
    });

 builder.Register(c => ConfigureNHibernate())
    .SingleInstance();
```

where ConfigureNHibernate(), which returns the base SessionFactory, looks like:

```
private ISessionFactory ConfigureNHibernate()
{
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration().Configure();
    cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Entity).Assembly);
    return cfg.Configure().BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

Currently, this is limited to just the one database.  In any other NHib scenario, I'd likely shove instances of the separate SessionFactories into a hash, and retrieve them as needed.  I don't want to have to re-architect the whole thing as we're fairly close to a major release.  So, I'm guessing I need to modify at least the methods above so that I can independently configure two SessionFactories.  My gray area is how I'll go about specifying the correct Factory be used with a specific repository (or at least for entities specific to that second database).

Anyone have experience with this scenario while using an IoC container and NHibernate in this manner?

**EDIT**
I've stubbed out a GetSessionFactory method that takes a configuration file path, checks for the existance of a matching SessionFactory in the HttpRuntime.Cache, creates a new instance if one doesn't already exist, and returns that SessionFactory.  Now I still need to hammer out how to tell Autofac how and when to specify an appropriate config path.  The new method looks like (borrowed heavily from Billy's 2006 post [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/NHibernateMultipleDBs.aspx)):

```
private ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory(string sessionFactoryConfigPath)
    {
        Configuration cfg = null;
        var sessionFactory = (ISessionFactory)HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(sessionFactoryConfigPath);

        if (sessionFactory == null)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(sessionFactoryConfigPath))
                throw new FileNotFoundException("The nhibernate configuration file at '" + sessionFactoryConfigPath + "' could not be found.");

            cfg = new Configuration().Configure(sessionFactoryConfigPath);
            sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

            if (sessionFactory == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("cfg.BuildSessionFactory() returned null.");
            }

            HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(sessionFactoryConfigPath, sessionFactory, null, DateTime.Now.AddDays(7), TimeSpan.Zero, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.High, null);
        }

        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

Comment: Storing the session factory in cache is a bad idea. It's not something that can just vanish and be recreated.

Comment: I know.  In reality, I'm going to have to manage the lifetime of that cached object.  Billy's example actually takes this a step further and created a singleton scoped SessionManager class that takes care of the caching concerns.  I was trying to dumb it down so I could eventually let Autofac manage it via it's own (very elegant) scoping mechanisms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want different types of entities to go into each database; if you want to keep the same kinds of entities in each database, check out AutofacContrib.Multitenant.

The two ingredients that can help with this scenario are:

- Named services http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/TypedNamedAndKeyedServices
- Resolved parameter http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/ResolveParameters (minimal docs on this one - the coming Autofac 2.4 release has some syntax sweeteners around this...)

First, use named services to refer to the two different databases. I'll call them `"db1"` and `"db2`". All of the components relating to the database, all the way up to the session, get registered with a name:

```
builder.Register(c => ConfigureDb1())
    .Named<ISessionFactory>("db1")
    .SingleInstance();

builder.Register(c => c.ResolveNamed<ISessionFactory>("db1").OpenSession())
    .Named<ISession>("db1")
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

// Same for "db2" and so-on.
```

Now, assuming you have a type `NHibernateRepository<T>` that accepts an `ISession` as its constructor parameter, and that you can write a function `WhichDatabase(Type entityType)` that returns either `"db1"` or `"db2"` when given the type of an entity.

We use a `ResolvedParameter` to dynamically choose the session based on the entity type.

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(NHibernateRepository<>))
    .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
    .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
        (pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(ISession),
        (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<ISession>(
            WhichDatabase(pi.Member.DeclaringType.GetGenericArguments()[0])));
```

(Warning - compiled and tested in Google Chrome ;))

Now, resolving `IRepository<MyEntity>` will select the appropriate session, and sessions will continue to be lazily initialised and correctly disposed by Autofac.

You will have to think carefully about transaction management of course.

Hope this does the trick!
NB

Comment: Dude, that was it.  So awesome!  I had some tweaking to do for my scenario, and dug in a little more into the updated Autofac source so I understood what was going on, but hell yes, this is why I love SO!  Thanks Nicholas!